# Error when installing postgresSQL in Windows "C extensions are not supported"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, jruby

I've been trying to `gem install pg` on many different ways I've found on the internet and none work. They all give the same error.

What I've tried :

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3:

gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5:

gem install pg
```

Using `bundle install` after editing the Gemfile.

Every single time I get this error:

```
C:\laragon\www\ruby\Car-X>gem install pg Building native extensions.  This could take a while... C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:56: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160629-8568-1ou7emz.rb extconf.rb NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:944    (root) at C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:2

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection. Results logged to C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What is in the `C:/jruby-9.1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ruby devkit so that your ruby compiler can deal with native C code.
Check out the instructions on how to do so here:
https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Once you've installed it, make sure that your windows PATH environmental variable includes a link to the bin folder in your newly created devkit directory. (P.S. Make sure there are no spaces in the path to the directory).